# How to access application specific google calendar from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I need to integrate, application specific, google calendar with the backend spring boot application to get (create/delete/update too) all the events scheduled on the calendar account. Basically need to provide REST APIs to perform all these operations.This is not a user google account. All the users logged into the application should be allowed to see the calendar events. My questions are:

1. Does this need a service account or Oauth2 credentials ?
2. Is google service account free?
3. Application uses JWT security to access all the apis, does this have any impact?

   Looking forward for answers and suggestions to go about this.

   Thanks